# XAMPP on MacOS - use localhost instead of IP address

Tags: macos, xampp, localhost

I am trying to switch web development from Windows to Mac but I have encountered a problem which would need me to alter a lot of existing code.

I am running Apache and MySQL using XAMPP.

Basically, I want to access a PHP Rest API which I have created on a Windows system where I can access it like this:

```
http://localhost/api/read.php
```

However, on Mac I have to access it like this (with XXX.XXX.XX.X being my local IP address) which works perfectly fine:

```
http://XXX.XXX.XX.X/api/read.php
```

But when I try to access localhost (the same way as I did on Windows) I get an error:

```
Safari cannot establish a connection to the server.
Safari cannot open the site "localhost", because Safari cannot establish a connection to the server.
```

Is there a way to "enable" access via localhost on Mac without using the IP address?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You may be installed the application that sets up a virtual machine.

Go to download page again.

here: https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html

Now select "**7.3.0 / PHP 7.3.0**" or latest version according to your visit time **without 'VM'**.

Remember **don't select "*XAMPP-VM / PHP 7.3.0*"** or latest version **with 'VM'**